# Is reciting the Qur'an while standing (as is commonly done in Taraweeh) halal or haram?

Tags: salat, taraweeh

I have a question: My friend said we should not offer *Taraweeh* because reading reciting the *Qur'an* while standing is *haram*, but is reading *Qur'an* while standing actually *haram*?  And if it is *haram* then wouldn't offering *Salah (Prayer)* also be *haram*?

Can I get a correct answer for this because I am confused for what is correct and what is wrong?

Comment: Then almost every Namaz is haram. Seems your friend is a little confused. The only reason to recite Qur'an while sitting (not while praying) is because it is said that we should respect Qur'an. In fact, there are no rulings which prohibit that AFAIK. So, Taravee is Halal and Sunnah.

Comment: Thank you vry much i got my answer and i can probably do what i want

Comment: You should mark the following answer as 'Accepted' if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear: 
The prayer is an independent kind of worship which in fact combines the 4 other pillars of islam! A part of a prayer as the Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) taught as is reciting the fatiha and some verses of the Quran while standing! Therefore praying Taraweh or any other prayer as we do is perfectly permissible and sunna (if not even fard/farz for those who can stand!)!

Now is it' permissible to read/recite Quran while standing?

Well yes it's not common if we exclude the daily prayers. And standing and reading Quran is neither convenient nor very helpful to concentrate on this kind of worship (if it's not during a prayer).

But Allah (Ta'ala) says in the Quran:

> - **Who remember Allah while standing or sitting or** [lying] **on their sides** and give thought to the creation of the heavens and the
>     earth, [saying], "Our Lord, You did not create this aimlessly; exalted
>     are You [above such a thing]; then protect us from the punishment of
>     the Fire.
>
> [Surat al-I'mran (2:191)]
>
> - And when you have completed the prayer, **remember Allah standing, sitting, or** [lying] **on your sides.** But when you become secure,
>     re-establish [regular] prayer. Indeed, prayer has been decreed upon
>     the believers a decree of specified times.
>
> [Surat an-Nisa' (4:103)]

remember Allah: is dhikr Allah this mean's dua', dhikr/tasbih/tahlil/takbir/ and of course also reciting Quran!

This mean's we can read Quran in any position as long as we do it as it should with the right concentration...

as an Addition here a [Fatwa](http://www.binbaz.org.sa/node/11251) (Arabic)

And Allah knows best!